# FIND A SPECIFIC FILE IN A FOLDER "C:\TEST" THAT CONTAINS MULTIPLE ARCHIVES ".ZIP" USING C#

Tags: c#, zip, compression, c#-ziparchive

I have a folder "`c:\test`" which contains multiple archives. How do I search through all the archives in this folder for a specific file.

This only search a particular archive using `ZipPath`:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string zipPath = @"C:\Test\archive1.zip";
        string filetosearch = "testfile";
        using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
        {
            foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
            {
                var position = entry.Name.IndexOf(filetosearch , StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
                if (position > -1)
                {
                    listView1.Items.Add(entry.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to search all the archives in this folder i.e `archive1` to `archive70`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
foreach(var zipPath in Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Test"))
{
    using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
    {
        foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
        {
            var position = entry.Name.IndexOf(filetosearch , StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            if (position > -1)
            {
                listView1.Items.Add(entry.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code gets all the files in the directory and iterates through them. If you need to filter the files by extension you can check it inside the foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something along the lines of

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\Test\", "*.zip")
```

Then change you click code to

```
foreach(var filePath in filePaths){
    //your code here for each path
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use following code

```
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\test", "*.zip");
        string filetosearch = "testfile";
        foreach (var item in filePaths)
        {
            string name = Path.GetFileName(item);
            if (name.IndexOf(filetosearch, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
            {
                //item is path of that file
            }
        }
```